# How can I tunnel https callbacks from paypal to my local dev in a serverless way

Tags: azure-functions, serverless, ngrok

I'm trying to develop against PayPal but I don't get any callbacks because I'm on my local dev computer.
Stripe has a CLI that tunnels callbacks to your local env but PayPal does not.
Is there an easy way to run a serverless tunnel e.g ngrok using an azure function or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com/) is indeed one way to achieve this and should be fairly straightforward. But if the free tier doesn't work for you, here is another way you can work with callbacks

- Use an [Azure Event Grid Topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/concepts#topics) as the endpoint for your callbacks (configure this in PayPal)
- Setup a subscription to [send events to a service bus queue / topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-handlers#service-bus).
- Instead of a HTTP Triggered Function, use a [Service Bus Triggered Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp) which will process messages in the queue